# Solving a DE using substitution method. Please Help!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm attempting to solve the following DE:

$$y^2\frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{y^3}{x}=\frac{2}{x^2}$$

with the substitution $u(x) = y^3$

I can somewhat picture what needs to be done, but I seem to come up short.  For instance, I know the following:

$$u(x) = y^3$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}= 3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{3y^2}\frac{du}{dx}$$

Furthermore:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3u^{\frac{2}{3}}}\frac{du}{dx}$$

Substituting this into the DE is where I'm getting stuck.  I can't seem to get it to "work" after that point.

I would certainly appreciate any help!

Comment: You are going a bit astray after getting $du/dx=3y^2(dy/dx)$.  Can you see a *really easy* way of substituting this into your d.e.?

Comment: Well, I thought that I could apply the chain rule, since y^3 is already part of the DE, but I couldn't make sense of it.  Is that what you were referring to?

Meaning that (1/3) du/dx = y^2(dy/dx) which is already a part of our DE.

Sorry if I'm not quite following your lead.

Comment: Look carefully at your expression for $du/dx$ and at the first term of the d.e.  (Or see @Andre's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply your fierst equation by 3 to egt
$$\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{3}{x}u=\frac{6}{x^2},$$
Which is a linear DE, using the integrating factor you can solve it as follows
$$\beta=\exp{\int \frac{3}{x}dx}=x^3\\
u=x^{-3}\{\int x^3*\frac{6}{x^2}dx+c\}$$

Comment: OK, I see that now!

It was right in front of me!

Comment: Many thanks, Semsem.  I just started this course, so I'm getting used to seeing those sorts of formatting.  But I absolutely know what you mean now.

Comment: So you accept my this answer, as always if you face any problem just let me know

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** By what you wrote, we have
$$\frac{1}{3}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{u}{x}=\frac{2}{x^2},$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{3}{x}u=\frac{6}{x^2}.\tag{1}$$
You will not have any trouble with the equation $\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{3}{x}u=0$. You will also need a particular solution of (1).

Comment: Andre - 

Thanks very much for the reply.  I'm confused by what you mean when you say "you will not have any trouble with the equation...".  

If I subtract (3/x)*u from both sides of the equation and then factor it out from the RHS, it appears as though there are now two solutions to du/dx.

I apologize if I'm having trouble following you - I don't normally seek help online, but I'm grateful for the help!

Comment: The DE $\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{3}{x}$ is separable, we get $\frac{1}{u}du=-\frac{3}{x}\,dx$, $\ln u=-3\ln x+K$, so $u=Cx^{-3}$. By the way, one particular solution of (1) has shape $\frac{k}{x}$, you need only find $k$. There are other ways to solve the linear DE (1), use whichever you were taught.